# Automatically execute commands when logging to windows via ssh without using powershell

Tags: windows-10, macos, command-line, ssh, openssh

I use VSCode remote development to write code on a Macbook and then build the code on a remote machine running windows 10. I have set up a ssh server in the windows box with key authentication and I would like to increase the automation by creating some aliases that will execute tasks on the remote host.

Unfortunately I can't use powershell because for some reason many of the build commands are not available in powershell (beats me why, they just don't function the same way as form the cmd prompt... I'm assuming it's due to some pre-set envs...) and to make matters worse, I can't seem to make my cmd_profile work on the windows host.

How could I mimic the behavior of a .bashrc in the remote (Windows) host so that when I log through ssh it automatically executes some commands?

And would there be a best way to implement aliases that quickly execute procedures from the cllient?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the tooling for the build pipeline on the remote Windows host? If you get that to work with PowerShell you can leverage its `$PROFILE` to add tasks, aliases and functions that are being run upon launching PowerShell.

Comment: that's a bit out of my depth... the build pipiline is executed from a remote share which needs to be initialized first like so: \\share\tool\tool_initializer
once this command executes it apends the PATH to a whole bunch of other commands which I rely on to build...
I just found out however that this share is giving me access denied error, probably due to the key authentication (it used to work when I was prompted for password

Comment: Sounds like you need to explicitly map the share with net use, e.g.: `net use S: \\$FILESERVER\$SHARE /user:$USERNAME $PASSWORD` before you can continue with the rest of the steps.

Comment: that worked, thanks!... now on to having that work on poweshell... if I rdp into the remote host and try to init the build pipeline via powershell nothing seems to happen and subsequent commands that should have been made available return the 'command_name is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.' error...

Comment: Is the tool initializer a Windows batch script per chance, i.e. a .cmd or .bat file?

Comment: yes, if I navigate to the share it has the .bat extension